# Testing for null and something else on the same line of code

Tags: asp.net

I have a user object and I have a variable named userID.

I would like to test 2 things:

- user == null
- user.UserID != userID

The second test must be done only if user is not null otherwise I have a runtime error.

I wonder if it is possible to test both on the same line, something like below:

```
return ((user == null) && (user.UserID != userID))
```

But coded like above doesn't work because when user is null I have a runtime error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume C# and that you want a boolean value == true when the user is null **OR** userid is different from user.UserID. So the answer is:

```
return ((user == null) || (user.UserID != userID));
```

The OR logical operator stop its evaluation of the expression as soon as it finds a true condition  starting from the leftmost one.

In this case if user is null, you have your result (True) and there is no need to test the second condition, therefore you avoid the null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do a check in one line, but you should use an `or` condition

```
return ((user == null) || (user.UserID != userID))
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I think is easiest to read is:

If you want **true** if user is null:

```
return user == null || user.UserID != userID
```

If the first condition *is* met (it's true), then it won't check for the second.

Or if you want **false** if user is null:

```
return user != null && user.UserID != userID
```

If the first condition is *not* met (it's false), then it won't check for the second. The power of `&&` and `||` =)